# Error al Seleccionar Registros con EntityFramework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Clase que recibe los datos de la consulta

```
public class EngineEntity
    {

        public string FacturaId { get; set; }
        public string  Cliente { get; set; }
        public int? TipoFactura { get; set; }
        public double?  Monto { get; set; }
        public double? Impuesto { get; set; }
        public double? Total { get; set; }
        public string OrdenCompra { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Fecha { get; set; }
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public double? Cantidad { get; set; }
        public double? Precio { get; set; }
        public double? SubTotal { get; set; }

    }
```

Este es el metodo donde ejecuto la consulta ...pero en el WHERE me dice que no se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo string en Boolean
Que estare haciendo mal??

```
 public IQueryable<EngineEntity> FacturaInformacion(string FacturaId)
        {
            IQueryable<EngineEntity> valor;
            EMCEntities1 Modelo = new EMCEntities1();
            using (Modelo)
            {
               valor = from a in Modelo.FacturaDatos
                       join b in Modelo.FacturaDetail on a.FacturaId equals b.FacturaId where a.FacturaId = FacturaId
                       select new EngineEntity
                           {
                             FacturaId = a.FacturaId,
                             Cliente = a.Cliente,
                             TipoFactura = a.TipoFactura,
                             Monto = a.Monto,
                             Impuesto = a.Impuesto,
                             Total = a.Total,
                             OrdenCompra = a.OrdenCompra,
                             Fecha = a.Fecha,
                             Codigo = b.Codigo,
                             Descripcion = b.Descripcion,
                             Cantidad = b.Cantidad,
                             Precio = b.Precio,
                             SubTotal = b.SubTotal
                          };
            }
            return valor;
        }
```

Comment: Haz intentando imprimir la consulta antes de asignarla a algun objeto? Puede que los valores que devuelve tu join no este correcto a como creas tu objeto!

Comment: El error se marca antes de ejecutar la app , pero el el SqlManagerStudio funciona bien

Comment: Me imagino entonces que te dira donde no se puede hacer esa conversion que linea etc?

Comment: pues si tu codigo esta igual al que publicaste te falta un '=' -->
where a.FacturaId == FacturaId

Comment: @EfrainMejiasC Si te ha válido la respuesta se agradecería que marcaras la pregunta como respondida para que el resto de la comunidad pueda beneficiarse de ella.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es que estás utilizando el operador de asignación (=), no el de comparación(==). La cláusula *Where* recibe un árbol de expresión con un delegado *Func* , por eso es que se puede hacer la comparación. Basta con que arregles el signo y listo.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba a cambiar el final del where de tu clausula where por esto:

```
where a.FacturaId == FacturaId
```

Y si no funciona por esto:

```
where a.FacturaId equals FacturaId
```

Si no te funciona dímelo a ver si veo alguna otra solución.